# how to exclude output with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to remove `amazon` and `downloadAll.sh` from output.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

```
❯ ls | sed 's/[^0-9]{1,4}//'                
downloadAll.sh
1041
973
295
127
273
221
1010
1152
227
937
994
210
572
1091
323
1328
472
1710
1192
1629
957
1167
1120
1628
1597
amazon
```

Comment: You are limiting yourself to only four occurences of your regex.

Comment: Also, use a 'g' after the final `/`.

Comment: Btw., parsing output from `ls` is bad practice.

Comment: I would start by not storing in the same directory data files and code, config or other files that are not meant to be processed automatically.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find` with a regex:

```sh
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/[0-9]{1,4}'
```

*Details*:

- `.` - search in the current directory
- `-regextype posix-egrep` - the regex engine is set to `egrep`, POSIX ERE (we can use `{min,max}` quantifier then with no extra escaping)
- `-regex '.*/[0-9]{1,4}'` - the filenames fully matching the regex will get returned. The `.*/[0-9]{1,4}` pattern matches anything followed with `/` + one to four digits till the end of string.

Answer (score 2):

To list files/directories ending with a digit use:

```
printf '%s\n' *[0-9]
```

To list files/directories NOT ending with a digit use:

```
printf '%s\n' *[!0-9]
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
# digits.sh
find                                                        \
    ./                     ` # search in current directory` \
    -maxdepth 1            ` # don't search recursively`    \
    | sed 's/.*[^0-9]$//g' ` # remove any file that doesn't end in a digit`
```

```
❯ bash digits.sh
./1328
./1091
./957
./1010
./210
./937
./295
./1597
./1629
./973
./1041
./323
./1192
./1167
./1710
./221
./42

./572
./127
./1628
./472
./1120

./227
./1152
./994


./273
./46
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an Extended Regular Expression (ERE) while `sed` is interpreting the script as a Basic Regular Expression (BSE), [here is the GNU sed manual's take on it](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-vs-ERE.html). Either convert to BSE or add the `-E` switch to the `sed` command for ERE interpretation.

However, for this simple task, `grep` is sufficient:

```
grep -x '[0-9]\+'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^[0-9]{1,4}$/!s/.*//' file
```

If a line does not contain 1 to 4 digits, replace it by nothing.

N.B. This will return a blank line for any line that does not meet the required criteria.

Perhaps what you really want is to delete such lines?

```
sed -E '/^[0-9]{1,4}$/!d' file
```

Of course to list 1 to 4 digit files can be achieved like so:

```
ls [0-9] [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```